# How to know which is the real drive behind the mapped block device?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, proc, device-mapper

I configured my box to boot from an alternative disk through modifying the existing os. However, some partitions are still being mounted from the internal storage.

In the case of the `/home` partition, I’ve `/dev/dm-0` which is used to decrypt the underlying block device.
But since it’s an exact copy (because I dumped in raw `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb`), how to know if the device behind `/dev/dm-0` is `/dev/sda47` or `/dev/sdc47`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -o +kname
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT KNAME
sdc         8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk             sdc
└─sdc1      8:33   0   3.7T  0 part             sdc1
  └─vol5  253:1    0   3.7T  0 crypt /vol5      dm-1
```

Alternatively:

```
ls -l /sys/class/block/dm-0/slaves

ls -l /sys/class/block/sd*/holders
```

The dmsetup mappings can also be shown using `dmsetup table`, although then you'll have to manually look up the maj:min number from either lsblk or /dev anyway.

Comment: Installing things is difficult in my case. Instead of installing it, isn’t there a place inside `/sys` where such information is written?

Comment: Installing? lsblk has been present in most Linux distributions by default for nearly a decade. Either way, see updated post.

Comment: How I can resize such mapped device to fill the underlying partition without dmsetup? Because the size reported is below the actual size.

Comment: Use `cryptsetup resize`, and if you don't have that either, then it should be enough to tear down and restart the mapping (e.g. by rebooting the system).

Comment: No I mean the exact command along with the key for creating the device (my system is using binary startup scripts) on an other Linux box. I think after that it would need resize2fs for ext4.